# How can I save ISPF Edit labels?

Tags: edit, mainframe, zos, ispf

When working in a large, or semi-large program under ISPF Edit I will define Edit labels to help me navigate around the source. These are great and do help **but** when I exit Edit the labels cease to exist and I have to recreate them the next time I edit that program.

Is there a way to save the labels when I exit Edit and then restore them when I return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: COBLAB Example]

Here is an image showing a sample use of the COBLAB command available with the SAVELAB package.

Answer (score 6):

There is just such a tool that I wrote a few years ago called SAVELAB. It will save all ISPF Edit labels on demand or when you end Edit and it will then restore them when you return by using the SAVELAB command.

This only works for ISPF Edit as SAVELAB is written is REXX as an ISPF Edit Macro.

It has two *bonus* commands called **COBLAB** and **REXXLAB** that can dynamically generate ISPF Edit label based on the contents of the Cobol or REXX code.

Find it at https://github.com/lbdyck/savelab